# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "me cago en la puta"?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, expresiones, españa

Llevo toda mi vida escuchándolo y en estos últimos años, de cuando en vez me he preguntado el por qué de esta frase ya que, leída literalmente, al contrario que otras frases hechas, es imposible verle el sentido por el cual *cagarse encima de una prostituta* podría ser un gesto de enfado o rabia.

Comment: A mí me gusta añadirle la coletilla _de oros_.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Las expresiones insultantes empiezan muchas veces por *me cago en...*,
>   siendo típica la referencia a la *madre* (en la madre que te parió, en
>   tu puta madre, en la puta de oros, en la puta de bastos, en la puta
>   madre que te cagó), a la *leche* (la leche, la puta leche, la leche
>   que mamaste), otros *parientes* (tu padre, tus muertos), o
>   *blasfemias* (en Dios, en diez, en la hostia, en el copón divino).
>   —De Miguel, Jesús M.; Moyer, Melissa G. *La cárcel de las palabras: ensayo sobre el lenguaje y la desigualdad social*

Lo anterior (y la propia experiencia) me sugiere que la expresión en cuestión está desemantizada y la «gracia» consiste en yuxtaponer una palabra malsonante —cual sea— al improperio, simplemente por la fuerza liberadora que le añade, sin importar que la yuxtaposición resultante tenga mucho sentido.

Comment: Visto así, tiene sentido, gracias.

Comment: Creo que hay una abundancia clara de expresiones sobre juegos de cartas. No me sorprendería que "me cago en la puta", viniera de "la puta de oros" o cualquiera similar. La puta se refiere a la sota, que es una carta que en algunos juegos supone la diferencia entre ganar o perder. Dada la afición a las cartas de los españoles, creo que podría ser éste el origen. Cagarse en la madre tiene muchas variantes sin "puta".